# maven modules execute built jar

Tags: maven, execute, multi-module

I have a multi module maven project,

I have 3 modules:

1. Source - The code that i am building - this outputs a .jar file
2. Java exec - builds a jar which takes a jar file as an argument, needs to be run with the jar from module 1, outputs a third jar.
3. Bash exec - A bash script which needs to be run with the path of the third jar above as an argument.

How would i do this?

i am assuming that i need to use the exec-maven-plugin for both of the modifier modules, but i have no idea how to pass the filenames between them

EDIT: before i split it into 3 modules, i had the bash exec working, but the java exec is new, but i think it should work the same as the bash exec

Comment: You can add dependency of module 1 in module 2 and module 2 in module 3. Not very sure how maven exec plugin works but it may have a facility to read the artifacts from running maven builder or the maven classpath.

Answer (score 1):

(Thanks to Shinchan for pointing me in the right direction)

Using the maven dependency plugin, it is possible to copy the output jar from one module to another:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>GROUP_ID</groupId>
                        <artifactId>OTHER_MODULE_NAME</artifactId>
                        <version>OTHER_MODULE_VERSION</version>
                        <type>jar</type>
                        <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/</outputDirectory>
                        <destFileName>FILE_FROM_OTHER_MODULE.jar</destFileName>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
                <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

This results in a file called "FILE_FROM_OTHER_MODULE.jar" in the build directory,
Now i can point the exec arguments at "FILE_FROM_OTHER_MODULE.jar"